# i want to exception handle with limited index ,here print all exception but i want to ptrint to be (*147 ) as 0 index position

Tags: java

`StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);

```
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            System.out.println("mail");
            String msg1 = "Hi";
        msg1 = "<b>Exception is===>'" + sw + "'. </b>"`
```

`output: Exception is===> 'java.lang.NullPointerException at  abcservice(Abc.java:*147) ataatorg.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use stream api:

```
            StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
            Arrays.stream(stackTrace).limit(i).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Where **i** is number of exceptions you want to be printed.

Comment: In this project use jre 1.7 so this method is not working.

Comment: So than u can output elements of the array through the loop...